# Best strategy for converting change in longitude and latitude to north, south, east, west in degrees

Tags: python

This is not a class assignment but a conceptual question I'm struggling with for a personal project.

I need to convert a large paired group of long and lat coordinate values that show a two-dimensional directional change to degrees change (0-360).

What are the fastest ways to make this kind of transformation? I am hoping to avoid nesting a lot of conditional statements.

Comment: Spherical trigonometry is your FRIEND.

Comment: Spherical Earth or oblate spheroid?  If spheroid, which spheroid model?

Comment: Spherical Earth.

Comment: And one more.  If you have access to a good university, with a Navy ROTC detachment (or the equivalent in your country), go make an appointment with the Professor of Naval Science (translation: commanding officer of the detachment), explain your question, and ask him NICELY for an introduction to the guy who teaches Navigation.  (Any branch will likely be able to put you in touch with someone, but this is closer to a Navy problem than anything.)

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the bearing between 2 Cartesian points with regards to the World Geodetic System? Or how to convert them to polar coordinates?

Comment: I want to get the angles between them, expressed in N,W,S etc.. along the spherical plane surface.

Comment: So assuming `p1=array(lat1,lon1)` and `p2=array(lat2,lon2)` and `x` is the directional change between `p1` and `p2`, would something like the following work: `x = ((((180 / pi) * atan2((p2[1] - p1[1]), (p2[0] - p1[0]))) + 360) % 360) - 90` .. that will get you the 0-360, then N/S/E/W is a matter of which quadrant your in (where 0 = N, 90 = W, 180 = S, 270 = E). This is for a simple Cartesian system though (i.e. 2 points on a grid); but the algorithm isn't too much different with regards to a Great Sphere (i.e. WGS-84 lat/long systems) .. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @txtechhelp This is indeed more or less what I landed upon.

Answer (score 1):

For accuracy better than the general tools use to gather the data is a Python module [pyproj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj)  Feed your data into something like the `odometer` function extracted from [waypoint.py](https://github.com/wadda/NxGPS/blob/master/waypoint.py)

```
from pyproj import Geod  # sudo pip3 install pyproj
geoid = Geod(ellps='WGS84')  # See pyproj documentation for other fun options

def odometer(start, end):
    """Calculate bearings and distance between start and end.

    Arguments:
      start (tuple of float): latitude and longitude of starting position
      end (tuple of float): latitude and longitude of ending position

    Returns:
      float: True North bearing start -> end
      float: True North bearing end -> start
      float: distance start <-> end in meters
    """
    try:
        bearing_to, bearing_fro, distance = geoid.inv(*start + end)
    except Exception as error:  # more specific?
        print("odometer({}, {}) created error:{}".format(start, end, error))
        return None

        bearing_to %= 360
        bearing_fro %= 360
    return bearing_to, bearing_fro, distance
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/python/geodesics.html) to find the azymouth (0 - 360) between 2 points in the WGS84 ellipsoid using the [Inverse method](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/python/code.html#geographiclib.geodesic.Geodesic.Inverse) and filtering its [results](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/python/interface.html#dict) as follows:

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

def orientation(startpoint, endpoint): # each point is a tuple of (lon, lat)
    return (
        Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(
            startpoint[1], 
            startpoint[0],
            endpoint[1],
            endpoint[0],
        )['azi1'] % 360
    )
```

The degrees can be converted to directions based on the [compass points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass). Here is a more [clean approach](http://climate.umn.edu/snow_fence/components/winddirectionanddegreeswithouttable3.htm).

I have used the following code and verified some results with this [online service](http://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/distance.php):

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

def orientation(startpoint, endpoint): # each point is a tuple of (lon, lat)
    azi = (
        Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(
            startpoint[1], 
            startpoint[0],
            endpoint[1],
            endpoint[0],
        )['azi1'] % 360
    )
    ranges = {
        (0, 11.25): 'N',
        (11.25, 33.75): 'NNE',
        (33.75, 56.25): 'NE',
        (56.25, 78.75): 'ENE',
        (78.75, 101.25): 'E',
        (101.25, 123.75): 'ESE',
        (123.75, 146.25): 'SE',
        (146.25, 168.75): 'SSE',
        (168.75, 191.25): 'S',
        (191.25, 213.75): 'SSW',
        (213.75, 236.25): 'SW',
        (236.25, 258.75): 'WSW',
        (258.75, 281.25): 'W',
        (281.25, 303.75): 'WNW',
        (303.75, 326.25): 'NW',
        (326.25, 348.75): 'NNW',
        (348.75, 360): 'N',
    }
    for i in ranges.keys():
        if i[0] < azi <= i[1]:
            return ranges[i]
```